# Open an Access database and run one of its Macros from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

From Excel, I need to open an Access database and run one of the database's macros.

I'm using Excel and Access 2007.  Here is my code in Excel:

```
Sub accessMacro()

   Dim appAccess As New Access.Application

   Set appAccess = Access.Application

   appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\blah.mdb"

   appAccess.Visible = True

   appAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro "RunQueries.RunQueries"
   appAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase

End Sub
```

In the Access database, there is a procedure named RunQueries in a module named RunQueries.

I get:

> Runtime error '2485':
>   Microsoft Access Office can't find the object 'RunQueries.'

I also tried

```
appAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro "RunQueries"
```

and I get the same errors message.

I argued against it, and I have to do it this way (meaning, I have to use Excel as a frontend to open several Access dbs and run their macros).

Comment: This question waits to be closed :-)

Answer (score 3):

What about this syntax ?
     `appAccess.run "RunQueries.RunQueries"`

By the way, I always avoid naming a module like a procedure. This is looking for trouble.

Comment: I tried this, and it did not work.  I then tried changing the name of the module so that it was different from the procedure name, and it still did not work.  The error is: 

Run-time error: '2517'
Microsoft Office Access can't find the procedure 'RunQueries.'

Comment: That error msg is a progress...I tested the syntax I gave you. It should replace the ...runmacro line in you example.
Is you procedure public ? Don't you have an Option Private at module level ?

Comment: oh, and
     Set appAccess = Access.Application
is not necessary unless you remove the "New" in the line above.

Comment: This didn't work for me either. Even with the sub being specified as public.

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub accessMacro()

   Dim appAccess As Access.Application

   Set appAccess = New Access.Application

   appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\blah.mdb"

   appAccess.Visible = True

   appAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro "Macro Name"  '<-- As it appears in the Macro Group in the Access Interface.   
   appAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
appAccess.Modules.Application.Run "macro_name"
```

The macro name doesn't need the Module name to function for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Sub accessMacro()

   Dim appAccess

   Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

   appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\blah.mdb"

   appAccess.Visible = True

   appAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro "RunQueries.RunQueries"

   appAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase
End Sub
```

Comment: Please add a code block for clarity and a small description of what this code does.

Answer (score 0):

The msdn site didn't shed too much light, but I have a feeling that their disclaimer applies here. Here's what they mentioned:

> If you run Visual Basic code containing the RunMacro method in a
>   library database, Microsoft Access looks for the macro with this name
>   in the library database and doesn't look for it in the current
>   database.

Of course they don't mention how exactly to remedy this issue! But after reviewing the answers above I think it would be helpful to post a full answer:

```
Sub accessMacro()

   Dim appAccess As New Access.Application

   Set appAccess = Access.Application

   appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\blah.mdb"

   appAccess.Visible = True

   appAccess.Run "RunQueries"
   appAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase

End Sub
```

This worked when I ran it. Good luck! :D
-Reverus

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't specifically address the "RunQueries" version, but this works in Access 2019.

Note that the Application object has to be created and initialized a bit differently than in the previous examples (and this ends with Set [object] = Nothing).

Although not mentioned, TXE_DEN.accdb has a tie-in to a separate library database MLO_Library.accdb and a lot of the subroutines in DEN access routines in Library.  The macro in the example is in the TXE_DEN database, not the Library.  If it were in the Library, I don't know whether it could be accessed through the TXE_DEN database as shown.

Also, in the Navigation Pane the example macro shows up in "Unrelated Objects".  So in other cases--e.g., RunQueries--it might be necessary to include a module name in the identifier.

And just to avoid confusion--this macro does not do anything to anything in Excel.  It's just "Well, I'm running THIS EXCEL stuff and I also need to run THAT ACCESS stuff, so I'll digress to Access and run that and then continue with my EXCEL stuff."

```
Sub Run_Access_Macro()

    Dim appAccess As Object
    Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

    Dim AccessDB As String
        AccessDB = "F:\PATH WITH SPACES\TDN\TXE_DEN.accdb"

    ' format: module.macro
    Dim AccessMacro As String
        AccessMacro = "0 - Import TDN"

    appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase AccessDB

    appAccess.Visible = True

    appAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro AccessMacro
    appAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase

    Set appAccess = Nothing

End Sub
```